# Computing tie strength from multiplex graphs

Tags: r, igraph

I have a number of overlapping `igraph` objects. I would like edges in each `igraph` object to have an attribute called `tie_strength` based on count of common edges between nodes (vertices).

```
e1 <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(1:10,20, rep = TRUE)))
e2 <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(1:10,20, rep = TRUE)))
e3 <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(1:10,20, rep = TRUE)))
merged_edge <- rbind(e1,e2,e3)
multiplex_g <- graph.data.frame(merged_edge)
E(multiplex_g)$tie_strength <- count.multiple(multiplex_g)
```

I do not know how to copy `tie_strength` to corresponding edges in g1, g2, g3. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please update this question with example graphs `g1`, `g2`, and `g3` and then specify based on those graphs how you would compute tie strength?

Comment: Essentially I am saying that tie strength = aggregate of different ties between alters. For example if g1 = advice network, g2 = friendship network, and g3 = manager network, and if alters "Bob" and "Jane" have ties in all three networks, then their tie strength is stronger than if they had say a tie in only one network.  In this case I would want to weight tie (edge) with 3 or 1 in g1, g2 and g3 (depending on case).